# Get remote ip via javascript bookmark on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to make a small snippet on Google Chrome (as a bookmark) so I can "alert" my remote ip adress, but it is not working as it gives me the following error :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://l2.io/ip.js?var=myip. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://stackoverflow.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

```
var url = "https://l2.io/ip.js?var=myip"
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function (data) {
  // code
}
httpRequest.open('GET', url)
httpRequest.send()
alert(httpRequest["response"])
```

How can I get around this problem ?

Comment: Is that your server you are calling?

Comment: https://l2.io/ip.js?var=myip is a webpage that show your current ip address, I want to crawl it using Javascript so I can output (as an alert) my current ip address by clicking a bookmarklet, but it doesn't seem to work (for security reasons, I can't call it on every websites)

Comment: Which is why I wanted to know if it was your server otherwise you could solve it without much effort

Comment: No it's not my server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get around this problem in a few ways. [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en), Chrome extensions or a Chrome app.

Here is an example using Tampermonkey.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Show my IP
// @version    0.1
// @include    /https?:\/\/*/
// @grant      GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @grant      GM_registerMenuCommand
// ==/UserScript==

GM_registerMenuCommand('My IP', run);

function run(){
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        method: "GET",
        url: "https://l2.io/ip.js?var=myip",
        onload: function(response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

This adds a menu option to the tampermonkey plugin called "My IP" that when you click it, it shows the alert box.

[image]